# Applications of Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, coloring, matching-theory

Presently I am teaching the Course "Graph Theory and Applications" to engineering students. I would like to teach some applications of graph theory in the class, like a stable marriage problem (matching), Scheduling problem (graph coloring), etc.  It will be helpful if some one provide some sources where I can find some interesting applications (based on planar graphs, connectivity, Ramsey theory etc)

Comment: Depending on what the students are interested in, they may find the concept of computational graphs interesting. This is a fairly relevant piece of machine learning currently, and the background of this course may give them insight into the meaning of different computational paradigms. For example, what does it mean that a Python library has dynamic computational graphs?

Comment: @Kumar. Please look at the question mentioned in the first comment. If you cannot explain why that is not enough, this is likely to be closed.

Comment: Stable marriage is used in ["the match"](https://www.aafp.org/medical-school-residency/residency/match.html)